# XYMultipleSeries graph not working?

Tags: android, graph, android-view, achartengine

I am trying to make a graph using [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html), except I can't seem to get it to work. My code is as follows. Note: `Default2` is an overlay that blocks views until user logs in, setting `Visibility(8)` means it is collapsed. `historyGraph` is a RelativeLayout that fills pretty much the whole screen.

```
    //TODO: Remove and place in Void currently at end of onCreate()
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finally", 1).show();

    default2.setVisibility(8);
    GraphicalView chartView;
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setShowLabels(true);
    renderer.setChartTitle("Test");

    XYSeriesRenderer r1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    XYSeriesRenderer r2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r2.setColor(Color.RED);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r1);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r2);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset data = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Series 1");
    XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Series 2");
    double[] first = {5,4,3,4,5};
    double[] second = {10, 8, 6, 8, 10};
    for (double i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        series1.add(i, first[(int) i]);
        series2.add(i, second[(int) i]);
    }
    data.addSeries(series1);
    data.addSeries(series2);

    chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getApplicationContext(), data, renderer);
    historyGraph.addView(chartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    historyGraph.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);        

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", 1).show();
```

Any one see why this ain't working?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? Not displaying? Any errors?

Comment: @mango it doesnt display...No errors.

Comment: @mango yes. Both of them. They trigger almost instantaneously. and setting the historyGraph backgroundColor doesnt show.

Comment: @Mango even though it is set to fillparent for both layout params and its parent takes up the whole activity (I set it to red to prove)

Comment: your code works fine on my setup. - except i commented out `default2.setVisibility(8);` perhaps this component, even collapsed is interfering with displaying the graph.

Comment: Hmm...Okay. I'll have a little bit of a play around.

Comment: So this didn't really look like an AChartEngine issue in the end.